# NoReverseMatch at //, Reverse for ' ' not found. ' ' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, pycharm

NoReverseMatch at //, Reverse for ' ' not found. ' ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

As part of Mozilla Development challenge under Django Development,The rest of the site works fine but when trying to visit the page where the borrowed books and logged in as librarian with the required permssion "can mark returned" i get the above error

**View.py**

```
class LoanedBooksAllListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
"""Generic class-based view listing all books on loan. Only visible to users with can_mark_returned permission."""
model = BookInstance
permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
template_name = 'catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html'
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    return BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='o').order_by('due_back')
```

**template**

```
 {% if user.is_staff %}
  {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}
  <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'all-borrowed' %}">All Books</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

**apps urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='my-borrowed'),
path(r'borrowed/', views.LoanedBooksAllListView.as_view(), name='all-borrowed'),
```

]

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/borrowed/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template E:\MDN\django_projects\localibrary\catalog\templates\base_generic.html, error at line 8
   Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' not found. 'renew-book-librarian' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :   {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
   5 :   <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   7 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   8 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.c om/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="s ha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   9 :   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pridi:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
   10 :   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   11 :   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   12 :   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   13 :   <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
   14 :   {% load static %}
   15 :   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '../static/css/styles.css' %}">
   16 : </head>
   17 : <body>
   18 : <section class="top">


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  442.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\JOACHI~1\Envs\joka\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /catalog/borrowed/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' not found. 'renew-book-librarian' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**bookinstance_list_borrowed_all**

```
<h1>All Borrowed Books</h1>

{% if bookinstance_list %}
<ul>

  {% for bookinst in bookinstance_list %}
  <li class="{% if bookinst.is_overdue %}text-danger{% endif %}">
    <a href="{% url 'book-detail' bookinst.book.pk %}">{{bookinst.book.title}}</a> ({{ bookinst.due_back }}) {% if user.is_staff %}- {{ bookinst.borrower }}{% endif %} {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
  <p>There are no books borrowed.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add code from `LoanedBooksAllListView` view.

Comment: Your traceback shows an error in `base_generic.html`. The error seems to suggest you have `{% url 'renew-book-librarian' %}`, but you haven't shown any URL patterns with that name - you have only showed ` name='my-borrowed'` and `name='all-borrowed'`. The template you have posted doesn't include `{% url 'renew-book-librarian' %}`, so make sure you have saved any changes and restarted `runserver` so that you are sure you are running the code you think you are.

Comment: Can you show which template has the code which gives this error?

Comment: Please add template `bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html`

Comment: @SergeyPugach the code for  `LoanedBooksAllListView` and `bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html` have added them, the earlier i had included before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}Renew</a> "`

This is the issue. You don't have reverse with name 'renew-book-librarian'.

In order to fix that issue you need to add view with such reverse name:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='my-borrowed'),
    path(r'borrowed/', views.LoanedBooksAllListView.as_view(), name='all-borrowed'),
    # add this one
    path(r'borrowed/<int:bookinst_id>', views.LoanedBooksDetailView.as_view(), name='renew-book-librarian'),
]
```

And add `LoanedBooksDetailView` view.

Or change `url` to another view or to `#` while you doen't have proper url but want it to be impelented with empty url like:

```
 <a href="#">Renew</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro! Worked like a charm, as part of my training for now i just added `#` in the coming tutorial i will learn how to implement it with forms!